# Reimplement paintComponent(Graphics g)

Tags: java, paintcomponent, graphics2d

Is possible change implementation of paintComponent(Graphics g) method of created component? 

 
Usecase: (Simplified for 2 components)
 1. Create 2 components JLabel jlabel1, JLabel jlabel2 in some black box.
 2. Put them in to `HashMap<String, Component> components`, where first argument is id, and second are our components jLabel1, jlabel2. 
**This part is blackbox**. Components are provided in this HashMap.
 3. Load HashMap components, go over the components and get them from the map.
 4. **Here I need change** paining method of provided componets from HashMap.

Note: Change in this case means rotation. 
Note 2: I know how to do rotation. Problem is **how to reimplement paint(resp paintComponent) method of already existing component to be able apply the code which will do the rotation**. When components are provided as blackbox in hashmap.

**IS THAT POSSIBLE?**

Comment: Just to clarify:  You want to rotate JLabels which you did not create, correct?

Comment: Well not exactly. It could be any component in hash map, which I didn't create. 
Basically I want to rotate whole JFrame which represents some screen. The components of it are put into hash map (this I don't create) and the hash map is provided, than there is some complex mechanism with layers to get the components from map and put on the JFrame. 
Rotation = rotation with some angle (Math.PI) with center point which is center of the JFrame (== screen).

Comment: I have access to that JFrame or its contentPane (I can modify the creation of its instance), but overriding paint method is not enought to rotate the screen. Because after updating content of its components (the components from hashmap, for example the JLabels, but not only), the updated components are repainted incorectly nonrotated over rotated screen. So I assume I need to rotate all these components one by one. Do you understand it?

Comment: Are you always rotating at a right angle?

Comment: If you mean right angle = 90°, than yes. In this case I need rotate it 180°
It is because of different position of monitor. So theoretically it will only make sense rotation 90°, 180°, 270°. Rotation = rotation all components around the center of JFrame. The point of it that this thing I want to rotate represents one of 2 screens which are usually on 2 monitors. I have to put them onto one. It will be placed on wide screen and on 1st nonrotated screen you can look from one side and to 2nd screen I need to rotate you can look from another side.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own `MyLabel extends JLabel`. And override method `paintComponent(Graphics g)`. In your MyLabel component you can add flag to rotate or not label.

Comment: Don't understand. Points 1,2 are blackbox in my question. I'm not the one who creates the JLabel, it's already created. All is hashmap where it already is. How this advice should help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new class which extends a component and override the component's method in this class. Ex:

```
public class Label extends JLabel {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
}
```

Or, you can create a component and override its methods directly, ex:

```
JLabel l = new JLabel() {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't understand How would I use it?? Note points 1 and 2. are blackbox. I have on the input the hashmap with already created components.

Comment: @user1097772 There is no way of overriding an object's methods after it was created, I've suggested this because at point 1 you've said "Create 2 components" which lead me to believe that you're the one creating the objects.

Comment: ok so you just didn't read my question patient enought and ignore the word blackbox which is mentioned in almost every sentence. And the result is that it is impossible?

Comment: @user1097772 Yes, you're right, you've mentioned that the components are already created. In that case, you can rotate the images and add them as `ImageIcon`s to the `JLabel`s, ex: `map.get(id1).setIcon(rotatedImage1)`, this way you won't have to override the `paintComponent(...)` method.

Comment: What? Isn't that another misunderstanding? This will rotate only the content of the component but not the component itself if i understand it correctly. I need rotate whole screen (screen = JFrame, components from that hashmap are placet on that JFrame).